# include html file within an html file

Tags: html, include

I'm trying to include an html file within another html file. the include acts as a menu and footer. i'm using the current include syntax but my html data is not displaying on the page. my include files sit at the root. i've tried:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
<!--#include file="navigation.html"-->

<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>


<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="navigation.html"-->
<p>test<p>

<!--#include virtual="footer.html"-->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if your server has server-side includes (SSIs) enabled.

*edit:* Also, you should remove the first set of includes that come before the `html` tag - that's invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Apache webserver? Do you have "mod_include" enabled? Do you have either in .htaccess or httpd.conf the setting "Options +Includes" set?

Answer (score 1):

Includes are server side, you'll need to save the main file as an .asp file and work with it on a server (assuming your server is ASP enabled, your syntax certainly makes that look as if it's the case).

Answer (score 1):

a lot of info lays here: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html, if it runs in the server i would go for `<?php include("filename.html"); ?>` since most of the servers also have php, if not you can always use .js
P.S. i won't mentions html possible problems since other answers i think mentioned all i know...

Answer (score 0):

The Netscape Navigator frames extension (cf. [Wikipedia's *Framing* article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_%28World_Wide_Web%29)) and its successors allow you to write HTML pages that reference other pages for inclusion.  The browser then assembles the viewed page by making multiple HTTP requests.  Note:

1. It's a horrible way to serve up webpages: there's no well-behaved document model for it.  But it is fairly well supported by browsers.  So this answer is for information's sake, not a recommendation; and
2. It creates viewed pages by juxtaposition, not inclusion, so it's not really what you were after, semantically speaking.  But you can use it to solve your problem: the menu and footer bars are mini HTML pages that sit next to the page containing the main content.